# Prove that $a=b$ when $a \le b$ and $a \ge b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \le b$ and $a \ge b$, then $a=b$.

1. $a<b$ or $a=b$ and $a>b$ or $a=b$  the intersection of two unions
2. $a=b$                        comparison/trichotomy postulate?

I really have no idea how to go about proving this theorem. Its pretty obvious that a=b. Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: The more pertinent question is: What do you have available to use in proving this, because this is so basic, that it's easy to want to tacitly assume something that you know that's equivalent to it, or depends on it. The way I'd approach this via logic (equivalent to the 'intersection of two unions' approach; noting that the 'or' here is actually exclusive due to how those inequalities are defined).

Comment: Does $R$ mean $\Bbb R$, the set of real numbers? What is the definition of $\ge$ and $\le$ you are using?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, R means the real numbers. . What do you mean by definition of $>=$ and $<=$? I know the first book I studied through defined <= as less than or equal to. It also defined $and$ as the intersection of sets.

Comment: See [the definition of a total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: What I mean is, to prove a result like the one you asked about, you need a definition of what $a \le b$ means. For example, let's say you had to prove this for integers instead of reals. For integers, $a<b$ means that $b$ can be reached from $a$ by adding 1 a finite number of times. Then you can prove that $a<b$ and $b<a$ can't be true simultaneously (due to the way integers are defined). Then you extend the definition and the result to rational numbers. Then you define real numbers as Dedekind cuts; a real number is positive if the "right side" of the cut contains only positive rational #s.

Comment: Then you can proceed to prove that $<$ is anti-symmetric using properties of real numbers (Dedekind cuts) and the same result for rational numbers. If this is way beyond what you did in class (I don't know - are you in middle school or in college?) then the problem itself is meaningless/unfair.

Comment: Use the laws of trichotomy.  It's a perfect set up.  $a \le b $ so $a <b $ or $b= a $ so it is not the case $b >a$.  Likewise $a\ge b $ means it is not the case $a < b $.  So two of three options are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First, we note that both 'and' (denoted $\land$) and 'or' (denoted $\lor$) are commutative, meaning that $a\land b=b\land a$ and $a\lor b=b\lor a$.

Beginning with the definitions of $\leq$ and $\geq$, we rewrite:
$(a\leq b)\land(a\geq b)$ as:

$((a<b)\lor(a=b))\land((a>b)\lor(a=b))$

Now we apply and/or distribution (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property; section on Propositonal Logic), but on the right instead of left (valid by commutativity) to obtain:

$((a<b)\land(a>b))\lor(a=b)$

But $(a<b)\land(a>b)$ is *always false* by definition of $<$ and $>$, thus:

$((a<b)\land(a>b))\lor(a=b)$ simplifies to $(\mathrm{false})\lor(a=b)$ which is true exactly when $a=b$.

Note how important it is to use the definitions of $\leq$, $\geq$, $<$, and $>$ (and I didn't spell that part out because idk what your definitions for those look like).

Answer (score 0):

It is Better to use law of trichotomy since $$ a,b \in R $$.

According to this law,only one of the following three relation hold,I.e.

$ a>b $          ,                         $            a<b $    ,   $       a=b$

If you say $ a<b$ and $a>b$ its a contradiction .hence we take a=b.

Comment: Did you mean to type "or" rather than "and"?

Comment: @fleablood Umm.... can u explain what you are asking please?

Comment: I mean a≤b and a≥b,is the intersection of two union.I.e 
((a<b)∨(a=b))∧((a>b)∨(a=b))

Comment: "If you say a < b *and* a >b it is a contradiction".  Did you mean that to be "and" or "or"?

Comment: "Is the inters of two unionunion"?

Comment: Is there any error in the answer???

Comment: I don't think so but I don't understand that 1 sentence.  In claiming both $a\ge b $ and $b \ge a $ nowhere is anyone claiming *both* $a < b $ AND $a >b $.but $a < b$ contradicts $a\ge b $ and $a>b $ contradicts $a\le b $.  So either one of them causes a contradiction.  So I wondered if you meant "or".  Oh, maybe you meant "and" to mean both of then individually cause a contradiction, and not both of them together.

Comment: I mean "and" just as you say in last line

Comment: Okay, for what it's worth that interpretation, for me, would be the *last* thing I would think it meant.  If I see P and Q cause a contradiction, I naturally read it as $P \land Q $ causes a contradiction and not as: both P and Q each cause contradictions, which I would express as $P \lor Q $ cause contradictions.  It was, for me, very confusing.